# winmd cannot found when change configuration profile in UWP

Tags: configuration, uwp, winmd

I have a library in .winmd format and it works very well in Debug profile but when I create a new profile (copy from Debug), it throws an exception that the module cannot found. Did anyone get the same problem like me? When I changed to Debug again. It still works fine.

**UPDATE**

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="TreeViewControl">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\lib\TreeViewControl\TreeViewControl.winmd</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Could you provide more info? For example the contents of your csproj, so that we can see how the library is referenced?

Comment: because the content of csproj is to long so I just post a section that refenrence my project to winmd file

Comment: I directly add reference to the '.winmd' file, the content of `ItemGroup` looks like this `<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="RuntimeComponent1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=x86">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\RuntimeComponent1\bin\x86\Debug\RuntimeComponent1.winmd</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>`. I compiled my project successfully.